# Java imap connect to store with and without ssl

Tags: java, ssl, jakarta-mail, imap

i'm trying to connect to imap store based on users server. For example, i have multiple servers like 143 with ssl, and 993 without ssl. When i try to connect to 143 ssl server it says plain connection. Is there any way to connect to store like that?

And is there any other IMAP other than javamail in java?

Some code below->

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
String imapProtocol = server.getImapSsl() != null && server.getImapSsl() == true ? "imaps" : "imap";
props.put("mail.store.protocol", imapProtocol);
props.put("mail." + imapProtocol + ".port", server.getImapPort());
props.put("mail." + imapProtocol + ".host", server.getImapHost());

javax.mail.Session mailSession = javax.mail.Session.getInstance(props, null);
Store store = mailSession.getStore();
store.connect(server.getImapHost(), server.getImapPort(), username, password);
```

UPDATE (DEBUG)->

```
DEBUG IMAP: enable STARTTLS
DEBUG IMAP: closeFoldersOnStoreFailure
DEBUG IMAP: trying to connect to host "imap.itheme.mn", port 143, isSSL false
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE NAMESPACE STARTTLS AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=LOGIN] Dovecot ready.
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: LOGIN
DEBUG IMAP: protocolConnect login, host=imap.somemail.mn, user=zolboo@itheme.mn, password=<non-null>
A0 STARTTLS
A0 OK Begin TLS negotiation now.
A1 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE NAMESPACE AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=LOGIN
A1 OK Pre-login capabilities listed, post-login capabilities have more.
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAP: AUTH: LOGIN
DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE LOGIN command trace suppressed
DEBUG IMAP: AUTHENTICATE LOGIN command result: A2 NO [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Authentication failed.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're got the port numbers backwards.  143 is plain text.

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't clear enough, the server configuration is set to port 143 but also requires ssl. I cannot change the server configuration, it's not mine. What can we do in this situation?

Comment: Someone has screwed up your server configuration.  And/or you misunderstand the server configuration.  If you're connecting on port 143 **with** SSL and it's complaining that it's a plain text connection, guess what, it probably really is a plain text connection.  Try that.

Comment: Note also that you can simplify your program by just using the "imap" protocol and setting the [mail.imap.ssl.enable](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/package-summary.html#mail.imap.ssl.enable) property appropriately; JavaMail will choose the port number so you don't need to set it, assuming you're using the correct default port numbers.  You might also want to use the [mail.imap.starttls.enable](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/package-summary.html#mail.imap.starttls.enable) property if your server requires that with plain text connections.

Comment: thank you for your reply. When i try to connect with port 143 without ssl, it says Authentication failed. username and password is correct. I updated my question with some debug

Comment: Well now you've got the ports right for sure.  Are you really, really, really sure you have the right username and password?  Can you connect to the same server using Thunderbird, for example?  Does your username or password contain any special characters or non-ASCII characters?  How is the username and password entered into your program?  Have you printed them out just before the connect call to make sure they're correct in your program?

Comment: yes i'm sure username and password is correct, yes i've tried using other mail clients, no neither username and password contain special characters, i'm getting username and password by login window. yes they're correct.

Comment: Are you connecting using Thunderbird on the same machine that your Java application is running on?  Have you checked the log files on the server to see if it has any clues as to why it's rejecting your authentication?  Try setting the property "mail.imap.auth.plain.disable" to "true". You can also try setting the System property "mail.debug.auth" to "true" to get the detailed authentication protocol exchange, which might provide more clues.  But don't post it here!  You can send it to me at javamail_ww@oracle.com if you need more help.